# How can i properly use DLookup function to return strings?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

`Dim gen as String`

`gen = DLookup("gender", "Patient", "ID_patient='" & Me.ComboPatients.Value & "'")`

I get error runtime 3464 for mis-match-type data and i don't know why?

Comment: Is the patient id a number? If so don't put it between quotes.

Comment: ID_patient is a an integer, so what i have to write?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around Me.ComboPatients.Value. I don't know the vba syntax for concatenating the strings together but you want the runtime value to evaluate to (with patient id of 10, for example) : "ID_patient = 10". Note how 10 does not have single quotes surrounding it.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it and the right notation is: gen = DLookup("gender", "Patient", "ID_patient = " & Me.ComboPatients.Value) without the single quote as you suggested

Comment: Also, I have another question , i'm having some problems with multiple criteria for example this one: lower_limit = DLookup("lower_limit", "Threshold", "age= 'young (0-30)'" And "ID_par= " & Me.ComboPatients.Value And "gender= 'male'"). The notation is right?

Comment: I think the filter needs to be all one string, including ANDs and ORs: `"age = 'young (0-30)' And ID_par = ... etc. "`

Comment: I did it but it didn't work because AND's and OR's are not being coloured in the code in "blue"

Comment: If i do in my way they are coloured but the code doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data mismatch error occurs if ID_patient is a number type field. Do not use apostrophe delimiters for number type, only text type field. Use # for date/time type field parameters.

From your comment (should have edited question or started a new one), concatenation is not correct. `AND` must be included in literal string parts - will not be colored blue. Consider:

```
"age='young (0-30)' AND ID_par=" & Me.ComboPatients & " AND gender='male'"
```

or rearrange:

```
"age='young (0-30)' AND gender='male' AND ID_par=" & Me.ComboPatients
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem using your notation ;). Next time i'll edit the question or start a new one.

Comment: What if age and gender are equal to variables? for example:
lower_limit = DLookup ("lower_limit", "Threshold", "age = '" & rangeagein & "' And ID_par = " & ME.ComboPatients & " And gender = '" & gender & "'")

Comment: Looks fine. Does it work? I see you opened a new question.